# How to append rows and cell to an HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need help trying to dynamically create an HTML table using JavaScript.

Here is the html:

```
<table id="Table">
    <tr>
        <th>Record:</th>
        <th>Employee Name:</th>
        <th>Amount:</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I now want to populate that table with an array dynamically using JavaScript.
So far, here is what I have:

```
for(var i=0;i<info.length;i++){
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<1;j++){
        var td=document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
        tr.appendChild(td); 

        td=document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(info[i]));
        tr.appendChild(td);

        td=document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hours[i]));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
}
tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
body.appendChild(tbl);
```

It is not working... Any help?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Comment: Show all the relevant code. Where do you declare and set `tbl` and `tbody`?

Comment: It does not append anything to my HTML table. When I inspect with HTML, it is just blank.

Comment: Please provide more code, since you haven't mentioned what are "tbl" and "tbdy". And also check if the inner loop is reached by putting a alert outside of your inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using @ZMF's link

```
            table = document.getElementById('Table') 

            for(var i=0;i<info.length-1;i++){
                var record = i+1;
                var row = table.insertRow(1);
                var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
                cell0.innerHTML = record;
                cell1.innerHTML = info[i];
                cell2.innerHTML = hours[i];

            }
        }
```